Ability to set ClientCertificates after instantiating RestClient or custom Factory?
Our .NET application currently uses RestSharp v106 and Ninject. It uses client certificates to authenticate the user with a secured server. The user starts the application, selects one of the certificates installed in their Windows certificate store and unlocks it via their user password or other methods. At this point, the DI container has already created our  RestSharp.RestClient   instance.
Before restharp v107, we would use RestSharpClient.ClientCertificates to add or replace previously used certificates with the user selected certificate via an Authenticator-implementation. From v107 onwards, ClientCertificates is part of RestClientOptions and can only be set when instantiating a new RestSharp.RestClient.
We're currently thinking about implementing a factory similar to the simple factory - instead of base urls we would use certificate identifiers as Dictionary keys.
Are there an alternative way to set the certificate after instantiating the RestClient or is this factory a viable option?

Client options cannot be changed as it would require re-creating the HttpClient instance and will make the client not thread-safe. You need to create a separate class to do the initial work, and use it as a dependency for the normal client.

What do you mean with the second sentence? I'm not sure if I understood it correctly (excuse the brevity, comment char limit).
We could create an instance of HttpClientHandler and pass it RestClient(HttpMessageHandler). We can initialite our HttpClientHandler instance similar to RestClient#ConfigureHttpMessageHandler and - since we control the HttpClientHandler instance - we can update the certificates on the handler.
Did I understand that correctly?

Yes, you can do that, if the handler can be updated.

There are multiple possible ways to solve the issue outlined in my question.
Option 1 was writing a factory and delaying the instantiation of all RestClients that require a certificate until the certificate is available. We tested this approach and it worked great.
The second option is to setup an own HttpClientHandler and pass it to the RestClient constructor [0]. The HttpClientHandler provides a X509CertificateCollection property called ClientCertificates which can be used to add and remove certificates at runtime. However, doing this may not be thread-safe.

[0] We only used the HttpClientHandler directly with HttpClient. Due to external factors, we had to move away from RestSharp. It's reasonably safe to assume that using RestClient(HttpMessageHandler) with HttpClientHandler will work similarly.
